# Displaying heatmap with OpenGL using shaders

Tags: qt, opengl, glsl

I am trying to display a heatmap with OpenGL using shaders.

Here is my vertex shader:

```
# version 130 
void main (void) 
{       
    vec4 vertex = gl_Vertex;
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * vertex; 
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0; 
}
```

And here is my fragment shader:

```
# version 130 
uniform sampler2D heatmap;
uniform sampler1D colormap; 
void main (void) 
{   
    float temp = texture2D(heatmap, gl_TexCoord[1].st).r; // [0 - 50] degrees celcius
    float r = temp/50.0f;
    r = clamp(r, 0.0f, 1.0f); 
    gl_FragColor = texture1D(colormap, r);
}
```

Here is the code I call once to send the textures to GPU memory:

```
glGenTextures(2, textures);
GLenum errc = glGetError();
if (errc != GL_NO_ERROR)
{
    const char* errmsg = (const char*)gluErrorString(errc);
    std::cerr << errmsg;
}

...

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_1D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]); // makes the texture with id texture active

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, 100, 100, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, &data[0]);


glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, textures[1]); // makes the texture with id texture active
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
glTexImage1D(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, 3, 256, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, &rgb[0]);
```

Here data is a std::vector of 100x100 floats and rgb is a std::vector of 3x256 floats.

Here is my drawing code:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);                      // Draw A Quad
        glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0); 
        glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0); 
        glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0); 
        glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glEnd();
```

Do I need to call glTexCoord1f() for each vertex? These values are not used.

I am using Qt and QGLWidget in particular.

**I am not seing anything. What could be wrong?**

Some observations:
If instead set gl_FragColor = texture2D(heatmap, gl_TexCoord[1].st); inside the fragment shader I see the red component correctly.

In the code above glGenTextures fails, but I still can see the red component as described above.
If I move this call to just before glBindTexture it does not fail, but then I do not see anything!?

Comment: THere is a lot of code missing: your whole shader and uniform setup code. Also, it seems like you try to bind a 1D and a 2D texture to the same texture unit simultaneously - that is not goint ot work.

Comment: textures is declared as unsigned int[2]. The 2D texture is using textures[0] and the 1D texture is using textures[1]. It must be possible to bind a 2D texture and another 1D texture at the same time?

Comment: yes, but not on the same texture unit.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand. What is a texture unit? Is it the GLInts I get from glGenTextures? Do not a glBindTexture call unbind the last bound texture? If not how am I supposed to do this?

Comment: Having googled a bit it seems I am missing a call to glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1); before glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, textures[1]); Is that it?

Comment: well. that might be part of it. YOu also need to set your unifrom samplers accordingly.

Comment: Like this ?                                                    layout (binding = 0) uniform sampler2D heatmap;
layout (binding = 1) uniform sampler1D colormap;

Comment: with quite recent GLSL, yes. But not with `#version 130` as you use currently. You will have to set the uniform value from the client side.

Comment: By passing the texture names textures[0] and textures[1] as uniform  variables named heatmap and colormap?

Comment: no, you don't pass in the texture names to sampler varibales, by the texture unit index you want to sample from

Comment: You will get no speedup by using shaders only to display the heatmap. You need to push calculations there to get a speedup. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39839788/895245